# Создание автообновления

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, zip, visual-studio-2017

Я пытался создать автообновление своей программы через zip-архив. Для этого использую DotNetZip (Ionic.Zip.dll). Примерно авто-обновление происходит вот так: скачивается тестовый документ с сайта (в к-ром цифра версии), читается версия, если она больше чем версия в `Preferences.Settings.Default.ver` то
`Preferences.Settings.Default.ver = ver`:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                string url = "http://f0160057.xsph.ru/osiddev/app/version.txt";
                string file = "version.txt";
                wc.DownloadFile(url, file);

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("version.txt");
            ver = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
```

Cкачивается архив (update.zip) и запускается `DDctD_UpTW.exe` (главный exe выключается через `Process...Kill();`:

```
ver = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
if (Properties.Settings.Default.ver < ver)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("New version available");
                    wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(@"http://f0160057.xsph.ru/osiddev/app/update.zip"), "update.zip");
                    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(download_Completed);

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You have newest version");
                    this.Hide();
                    Window login = new Login();
                    login.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
                }
    private void download_Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        ver = ver + 1;
        Properties.Settings.Default.ver = ver;
        Process.Start("DDctD_UpTW.exe");
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
    }
```

В `DDctD_UpTW.exe` Разархивируется архив с заменой файлов:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Ionic.Zip;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace DDctD_UpTW
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Unzip();
        }

        public static void Unzip()
        {
            try
            {
                using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read("update.zip"))
                {
                    zip.ExtractAll("/", ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            Process.Start("MainExe.exe");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

**Но главная проблема:**
После разархивации и запуска основного exe он опять пишет `"New update available"`. Как это починить?

Comment: А почему не ClickOnce? Там этот механизм реализован "из коробки". Просто интересно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не даёте вашим настройкам штатно "сохраниться" на диск убивая процесс. Уничтожение процесса через

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

вообще нехорошая практика. Правильнее сделать "штатный" выход из приложения, тогда отработает сборщик мусора и, в частности, настройки сохранятся.

Однако, сохранить настройки можно и вручную:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.ver = ver;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
Process.Start("DDctD_UpTW.exe");
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

Но, если вы так сделаете, то тоже будет "нехорошо". Если ваш `DDctD_UpTW.exe` не српавится с обновлением, то будет рассинхронизация между настройками и фактическим состоянием программы. Правильнее проверять версию приложения после обновления из более "надёжных" источников, чем настройки.

Comment: в качестве более надежного источника лучше использовать версию сборки, которая прописывается во время компиляции. Разумеется, чтобы это работало, нужно не забывать повышать версию сборки в проекте или автоматизировать этот процесс

Comment: @rdorn Я бы не полагался на версию сборки, так как, с точки зрения обновлений, версия это более комплексное плнятие, обновление может быть связано с внешними ресурсами, например. Но, конечно, главное, чтобы версия бралась из скачанных данных, а не из локальных. Из отдельного файла метаданных обновления в идеале.